# Condition XPath Expression in SoapUI - how to compare two values stored in custom properties?

Tags: testing, xpath, expression, conditional-statements, soapui

I have successfully captured four values from a response. I need to check that none of them are the same as any other (without worrying about every combination). In theory, checking that Value1 <> Value2, Value2 <> Value3, Value3<> Value4 are all true.

I could go with a mathematical identity approach (eg where `Value1/Value2*Value2/Value3*Value3/Value4 = 0`). I am failing in what I actually put in the body of the Condition XPath Expression in SoapUI (and the help is woeful, as always). Pretty sure I don't need to worry about the namespace stuff.

Right now I have three separate conditions eg `${#TestCase#Value1} <> ${#TestCase#Value2}` but I am getting a "no condition is true for current response" message when I know that 3 of the four are true.

Also, if the condition I am looking for is true, I need to halt, or pop to a step that does nothing. Any ideas on that?

Full current entry in the Condition XPath Condition box is:

```
declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://transferobjects.abc.def.org.nz';
declare namespace ns2='http://abc.def.org.nz/api/serviceorder';
${#TestCase#Value1} <> ${#TestCase#Value2}
```

(but I am pretty sure the first three lines aren't even needed because I am not getting anything from the message response, I have captured those already into the valueX items above).

Comment: You tagged your question with `XPath`. Where `XPath` is,  is XML. Where is your XML? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: SoapUI calls the box Condition XPath Expression but the contents is pretty basic. I will edit the full content of my current entry, but the one line that I think matters was already above.

Comment: Ugh. Okay, just removed those three lines, because I thought they were superfluous, and changed the last line to: ${#TestCase#Value1} - ${#TestCase#Value2} = 0 and now it seems to work. Still need a tip on how I pop an alert if any of the tests are true.

Comment: Oh, good grief. Sorry folks, answered it myself. I now just have a basic set of three checks with or statements and send it to a Manual Teststep which is effectively a halt.  ${#TestCase#Value1} - ${#TestCase#Value2} = 0 or 
${#TestCase#Value2} - ${#TestCase#Value3} = 0 or
${#TestCase#Value3} - ${#TestCase#Value4} = 0